# Do any of the servers used to run Google Cloud Platform services use Kaspersky products?

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-platform

We use Firebase, Google Cloud Storage, Firebase Functions & BigQuery mainly. Our prospective client has asked us to fill out a lengthy security assessment. They will not work with any company that uses Kaspersky products. This is difficult to prove to them using our Google Cloud stack.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would an answer from random people on the net satisfy an audit? Seems like only Google can answer this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not Google Cloud Platform support. If you have questions about the services they provide, contact them directly and ask them. We have no information here about what products they use internally, and that question is not programming related as defined in the [help] guidelines. Besides, what would information provided here do to satisfy your client? *JohnSmith234 at Stackoverflow says they don't* most likely isn't going to work for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may help to point them to the Google Cloud subprocessors page: https://cloud.google.com/terms/subprocessors - these are companies that provide services to Google Cloud that may be used to process data.